# Use xinput to adjust scroll direction when logged in through nx-server/player

Tags: mouse-scroll, nx, xinput

I followed these instructions to configure natural scrolling for my normal ubuntu (11.04) desktop, and they worked just fine:

http://maketecheasier.com/reverse-mouse-scrolling-direction-in-ubuntu/2011/09/16

but those settings, even when I'm logged in as the same user through nxserver remotely don't apply. So I tried to adjust the scroll direction manually using xinput like so:

```
 xinput list 
"pointer"   id=0    [XPointer]
"keyboard"  id=1    [XKeyboard]
```

and then:

```
 xinput get-button-map 0
X Error of failed request:  XI_BadDevice (invalid Device parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_OpenDevice)
  Device id in failed request: 0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  15
  Current serial number in output stream:  15
```

to see the current button map, trying to change the mapping with:

```
 xinput set-button-map "pointer" 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
X Error of failed request:  XI_BadDevice (invalid Device parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_OpenDevice)
  Device id in failed request: 0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  15
  Current serial number in output stream:  15
```

results in the same error. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16"` that works for me.